# How to iterate through a list of slots and connect a signal to them

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to figure out how to connect a signal(s) to a slot that's held in a list of slot pointers or names. I am trying to use a lambda to potentially modify the parameter from the signal before passing it to the slot.For example:

```
class Device : public QObject {

public:
    Device(){}
    QMap<QString, const char*> slot_list;
}
```

```
class ReceiverOne : public Device {

public:
    ReceiverOne() {
        slot_list.insert("slotOne", SLOT(slotOne(float));
        slot_list.insert("slotTwo", SLOT(slotTwo(float));
        slot_list.insert("slotThree", SLOT(slotThree(float));
    }

slots:
    void slotOne(float value);
    void slotTwo(float value);
    void slotThree(float value);
}
```

```
class Connector : public QObject {
public:
    Connector(Device* d){
        QMapIteratorQMap<QString, const char*> i(d->slot_list);

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            i.next();
            if (i.key() == "slotOne"){
                connect(this, &Connector::signalOne, this,
                        [d, i](float val) {
                        // invoke d->slot_list.value("slotOne") here
                        // i want to modify the val before passing to the slot
                    });
            }          
        }
    }

signals:
    void signalOne(float val);
}
```

```
// main.cpp
Connector* c = new Connector(new ReceiverOne());
```

Any ideas how I can better achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: I would recommend using function pointers instead of char*.

Comment: Can you share with us what is the exact problem bcs now it is not clear what you are asking for.